# Checking out a project's first commit with git

Tags: git, dvcs

Is there an easy way to find the SHA1 of the first commit in a project with a long history with git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just off the top of my HEAD, this should get one of the 'first' commits of the current branch.

```
git rev-list --reverse HEAD | head -1
```

(If the branch contiains two unrelated branches which have been merged together, it's not guaranteed which root you will get but you could use `--date-order` to select the oldest.)

Comment: How about `git rev-list --reverse --max-count=1 HEAD`?

Comment: Arrgh, I should test before I post. :) Apparently the count is applied first, so that just gives the most recent commit...

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --reverse | head -n1
```