# Gitolite: calling VREF for all but one repo

Tags: gitolite

I have the following setup. I want to check that commits have a certain commit message format (line limit, etc.). I want this for all repos, but one or two.
How can I tell this gitolite without having to define a group `@check_msg` that contains most repos. This would be cumbersome...
In my `BADCOMMIT VREF`, I already included some lines to not check the message if it is called with NOCHECK.

Any ideas??

```
repo    testing
  RW+                           = @all
  ?     VREF/BADCOMMIT/NOCHECK  = @all

repo    @all
  -     VREF/BADCOMMIT          = @all

repo    gitolite-admin
  RW...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering:

- that a [**VREF**](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html) has no idea of the git repo name or path it is called from, adding:
- fallthrough means success (which means, as matt comments, that it will check *all* the VREFS)

The only solution seems for the VREF script "`BADCOMMIT`" to somehow detects it is in a git repo it should *not* test.
If, by convention, said git repo were to contain a **[git notes](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/11/git-tip-of-week-git-notes.html) (**which you can add at any time, without changing the git history, see [`man git notes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes)) with a certain title on this note, it could decide to not go on with its check.

Since there are few git repos which shouldn't be tested with `BADCOMMIT`, you could add a note to [the first commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270712/6309) of that repo.

That way, you don't need a `NOCHECK`, and you don't need to stop after a certain rule.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand what you mean. How can I invoke the VREF for all the other repos then?

Comment: How can I prevent gitolite from checking all available rules? I need it to stop checking after

    - VREF/BADCOMMIT/NOCHECK = @all

Comment: @mattmilten true. I have edited my answer to propose another idea.

Comment: Thank you! This should do the job. Although I would have preferred to switch checking based on the gitolite conf. I did not know about the notes feature in git.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using git notes, I suggest you do this:

```
repo    testing
  RW+                           = @all
  option badcommit.nocheck      = 1

repo    @all
  -     VREF/BADCOMMIT          = @all
```

Then, at the start of the VREF, you say

```
gitolite git-config -q $GL_REPO gitolite-options.badcommit.nocheck && exit 0
```

Much cleaner, and the knowledge of the exceptions stays within gitolite.conf.

(Assuming v3 of course).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I set up my configuration with the "git notes"-solution already and it works fine.